# Are vaishnava patha and shaivitee patha leads to same parmatman?

Tags: vaishnavism, shaivism

Are vaishnavism patha and shaivism patha leads to same parmatman / GOD ?

Comment: Vaishnavites call Brahman Vishnu, while Shaivites call Him Shiva. In Vishnu Purana, Lord Vishnu says to Lord Shiva 'those who worship You have worshipped Me. Those who reach Me, have verily reached You' (paraphrased)! So yes all paths lead to the same goal. Ekam Sat Vipra Bahuda Vadanti (Truth is One, Sages call it by various names)

Comment: And Lord Dattatreya is also united avatar of Lord Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva.

Comment: Also see my answer here:  http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13623/where-is-buddhism-also-considered-a-valid-path-in-hindu-scriptures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both leads to same parmatman.

> त्रयी साङ्ख्यं योगः पशुपतिमतं वैष्णवमिति
>
> प्रभिन्ने प्रस्थाने परमिदमदः पथ्यमिति च।
>
> रुचीनां वैचित्र्यादृजुकुटिल नानापथजुषां
>
> नृणामेको गम्यस्त्वमसि पयसामर्णव इव॥ ७॥
>
> The different practices based on the three Vedas, SaMkhya, Yoga, Pashupata-mata, VaishhNava-mata etc . are but different paths (to reach to the Greatest Truth) and people on account of their different aptitude choose from them whatever they think best and deserved to be accepted . But as the sea is the final resting place for all types of streams , You are the only reaching place  for all people whichever path,straight or zigzag, they may accept .

From Mahimna Strotra

Comment: This is the same verse spoken by Swami Vivekananda in Parliament of Religion...