# Where is Buddhism also considered a Valid Path in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: scripture, puranas, buddhism

The Philosophy of Buddhism is directly refuted itself in Brahma Sutras. But refutation of Philosophy doesn't mean that the path is not Valid.

> For eg. Adi Shankaracharya also refuted the Philosophy of Pancharatra Agamas. But he still considered Pancharatra are able to give Mokshya.

Adi Shankara himself respects Buddha in [Hari Shankara Stotra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11976/what-is-the-mystery-of-hari-sankara-stotra-composed-by-adi-shankara/11977#11977) as:

> पाठितकेतोर्जयिने प्रतीतसर्वज्ञ्यभावाय दयैकसीम्न्ने |
>  प्रायः क्रतु द्वेषकृतदराय बोधौकदाम्न्ने स्पृहयामि भूम्न्ने || १० 
>   **I worship the spiritual radiance manifested as Buddha, who was all-knowing, who was the conqueror of Mara, who was full of mercy, who was of the nature of Bodha (spiritual conciousness), and who was the adored of those who were opponents of Yajnas.**

The name Buddha is itself Sacred in Hindu scripture. He is also considered as 9th incarnation of Lord Vishnu among the major incarnations. Although there are also Hindu scriptures which call Buddha as deceiver. Padma Purana itself state that *'uttering'* name of Buddha can cleanse the sin of Brahmahatya.

> Padma Purana Uttarkhanda chapter 71.26-29
>   Matsya, Kurma, Varaha, Narsimha, Vamana, so also Parasurama, Rama, Krishna, **Buddha,** and after him is said to be (the incarnation of) Kalki. These ten are said to be (Vishnu's) ten incarnations on the earth. **Merely by (uttering) their names, (even) the killer of a brahmana is always purified. He, by reciting, muttering, meditating upon Vishnu's name in any manner, is freed.** There is no doubt that he would be Vishnu himself.

Such is the power of just name of 'Buddha'. 
Another popular misconception about *'Buddha'* in people is that he rejected the Vedas. But in fact Buddha rejected the Vedas because he considered Vedas avaliable at his time were altered.

> In the Buddhist Vinaya Pitaka of the Mahavagga (I.245) section the Buddha names these rishis. The names of the Vedic rishis were "Atthako, Vâmako, Vâmadevo, Vessâmitto, Yamataggi, Angiraso, Bhâradvâjo, Vâsettho, Kassapo, and Bhagu" but that it was altered by a few Brahmins who introduced animal sacrifices. The Vinaya Pitaka's section Anguttara Nikaya: **Panchaka Nipata says that it was on this alteration of the true Veda that the Buddha refused to pay respect to the Vedas of his time.**

So, the reason why Buddha rejected Vedas was because **he considered** True forms of Vedas were altered.

My question is, **Are there any Hindu scriptures which Validate also the path of Buddhism ? Is Buddhism also considered a Path which can help to realise the supreme ?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**22nd Chapter of YajnaVaibhava Khanda of Suta Samhita of Skanda Purana** deals with the validity of various paths. The chapter itself is named as as '**MargaPramanya Nirnaya'** which means '**Decision of Validity of Paths'**. There the Path of Buddhas and Arhatas is also considered one among the many paths.

> अथातः संप्रवक्ष्यामि मार्गप्रमाण्यनिर्णयम् ।
> श्रद्धया सहिता यूयं श्रृणुश्वं मुनिपुड़्गवा ।।
> वेदांश्च धर्मशास्त्राणि पुराणं भारतं तथा ।
> वेदाड़्गान्युपवेदांश्च कामिकाद्यागामानपि ।।
> कापालं लाकुलं चैव ययोर्भेदान्ह्विजर्षभा ।
> तथा पाशुपतं सोमं भैरवप्रमुखागमान् ।।
> तेषामेवोभेदांश्च शतशोऽथ सहस्रशः ।
> विष्वागमांस्तथा **ब्रह्मान्बुद्धार्हद्यागमानपि** ।।
> लोकायत तर्कशास्त्रं बहुविस्तरसंयुतम् ।
> मीमांसामतिगम्भीरां सांख्ययोगौ तथैव च ।।
> अनेक भेदभिन्नानि तथा शास्त्रान्तराणि च ।
> निर्ममे शंकर साक्षात्सर्वज्ञः संग्रहेणतु ।।
>
> Listen with faith, O sages, to what I say as to the truth of the various paths. Vedas, Dharmasastras, Purana, Bharata, Vedangas and minor Vedas; Kamika and other agamas; Kapala and Lakula in all their variety; the Pasupata, Soma, Bhairava and other agamas with their hundred varieties: Vaishnava and Brahma agamas; **the agamas of the Buddhas and the Arhats;** Lokayata, and the Tarkasastras in all their vastness; the profound Mimamsa, as also Sankhya and Yoga; **all these and many more Sastras, the Omniscient Divine Being has made in brief.**

#### Why There are Many Paths ?

> अधिकारिविभेदेन नैकस्यैव सदा द्विजा ।
> तर्कैरेते हि मार्गास्तु न हन्तव्या मनीषिभि ।।
> यथा तोयप्रवाहाणां समुद्र: परमावधि ।
> तथैव सर्व मार्गाणां साक्षान्निष्ठा महेश्वरः ।।
>
> **The wise say that each of these sastras is intended for a particular class according to the individual qualification, not all for one.** These paths are not to be rudely handled by the learned subjecting them to rigorous unrelenting logic. As all streams ultimately empty themselves into the ocean, so all these paths ultimately lead to the Mahesvara (/Great Lord) Himself.

Thus each path and shastras are according to individual qualification of People.

#### How Lord helps from Other Paths ?

> तत्तन्मार्गेनुगुण्येन साधकत्वं ह्युपैति सः ।
> तत्प्रसादात्क्रमान्मार्गान्विशिष्टानेति मानवः ।।
> तत्र तत्र स्थितो देवः प्रसादं कुरुतेऽस्य तु ।
> सोपानक्रमतो देवा वेदमार्गस्य हेतवः ।।
>
> **Worshipped in what form so ever by people as ordained in their respective scriptures. He assumes that form and takes the devotee on to the next higher step, By His Grace man attains to superior paths. The Divine Being worshipped in the form in which He is represented in these paths takes the devotee step by step onward to the path of the Veda.**

#### Why can't other Paths be wrong ?

> तस्मादुक्तेन मार्गेण शिवेन कथिता अमी ।
> मार्गा मानं न चामानं मृषावादी कथं शिव ।।
> महाकारुणिको देवः सर्वज्ञो निर्मल खलु ।
> तथाऽपि वेदो मार्गाणामुत्तम: सर्वसाधक ।।
>
> "**Thus these paths, laid out as they are by Shiva, are all of them true and serviceable. How can Shiva be a deceiver?** He is supremely merciful, omniscient, and altogether stainless. Yet of all the paths, the  path  of  the  Veda  is  the  best.  as  conducing  to  all  good."

Thus, as Lord is merciful he can't be deceiver. Other paths are also there because of his wish. So, in the 'Decision of Validity of Paths' ,Buddhism is also considered a valid Path among the many Paths although the best Path is the Vedic Path.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Many people think that Buddhism, Jainism and others can never lead to Moksha. Btw, you can add the word 'Jainism' in your question because Arhats are Arihant(omniscient beings) of Jainism.

Comment: @Pinakin ,the same text in the same paragraph says only hinduism leads to moksha,he didnt quote all of the text.

Comment: This is a very brilliant answer. +1