# Why is Buddha Pūrṇimā named so?

Tags: belief, rituals, practice, festivals, purnima

Is Buddha Pūrṇimā named so because of Gautama Buddha?

If yes, then how to reconcile its significance with our hindu theology because clearly, Gautama Buddha was not a Hindu as per Vedic Standards.

Or some other reasons, like the Full-Moon (Buddha Pūrṇimā) always coincides with Wednesday (budhavāra - बुधवार), and thus named so?

What's the theological significance of the Buddha Pūrṇimā as per Hinduism and why is it named so? What are the associated practices and rituals to be done on this day?

Comment: See this I’ve recently edited: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16515/adi-buddha-and-gautama-buddha-which-one-is-the-real-avatar-of-lord-vishnu there’s actually one more view in favour, even from Jyotisha which holds the Buddhist’s Buddha isn’t the avatar.

Comment: Well, @Archit  , if he indeed was an incarnation of the Lord or not, is still debatable. I personally don't consider him as an incarnation, rather an enlightened person - Mahāpūruṣha, who showed people an alternative, yet, an equally valid path to Mokṣha.

Comment: No, Buddha Purnima occurs on full moon of Vaishakha month(April-May) based on lunar Hindu calendars & comes from Vishakha constellation(which means branching). Kaliyuga started with death of Krishna around 3000 BC for 2400 years(1200 desc & 1200 asc) & ended with birth of Buddha(500 BC),an avatar of Ganesh (https://www.britannica.com/biography/Maha-Maya) marking beginning of ascending cycle to Satyuga for 12k years & Dwapra for 2400 years. Dwapra asc. ended around 1950 by freedom of all nations preceded by several saints like Ramana Maharshi, Swami Vivekanada, Yogananda, Yukteshwar giri etc.,

Comment: Right now we are in Treta beginning(for 3600 years) in Age of Aquarius(for 12000 years) of research, science & technology to reach Satyuga(of 9600years) again by 5500AD .http://www.dwapara-yuga.org

Comment: "always coincides with Wednesday (budhavāra - बुधवार)" -- this is not true..see few past years' days on Buddha purnima, they r not budhavāra..

Comment: Yes @YDS, that's a speculative statement. Veracity is to be verified.