# What is the meaning of contrasting (even conflicting) nature of various avatars of Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, avatars, buddhism, parashurama

You know for instance take the last 4 forms of lord Vishnu. There is Parshuram who is violent and slayer of his enemies meanwhile there is lord Budha who says no to harming others who try to harm us. Lord Krishna tells us slay the adharmis meanwhile lord Buddha tells us if someone wants to harm you let them harm you. I am really confused what is Lord Vishnu trying to tell us?

Comment: The Buddha you are referring to does not fit the qualifications for being an avatar. Have a look at : [Which buddha is the real incarnation of Vishnu](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16515/adi-buddha-and-gautama-buddha-which-one-is-the-real-avatar-of-lord-vishnu)

Comment: Lord Krishna's message in the Gita is regarded as authoritative in the Vedanta school.

Comment: There is no message. Each avatar plays a role in his or her story. In this context a specific avatar is required to uphold dharma.