# Is Brahman (as described by Adi Shankara) mentioned in the vedas?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, brahman

I was having discussion with in vedanta study group and there was an argument stated that "Brahman" as mentioned by Adi Shankara was not a concept mentioned in any of 4 vedas and that Shankara had a different interpretation of maya.

My question is:
1. Which vedic verses describe Brahman as stated by Adi Shankara?
2. Is Vedanta imparted from Buddhism? (sometimes Adi shankara is called as mayavadi or shoonyavadi).

Glad if you could give Vedic verse references to your answers.

Comment: Part of your question is relate to: [Why is Sankaracharya accused as Pracchana Bauddha (crypto-buddhist) by many Vedantins?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17249/277)

Comment: Also take a look at [Where is Buddhism also considered a Valid Path in Hindu scriptures?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13623/277)

Comment: No, current Buddhists and of his time are/were atheists. Shanakara was never an atheist else he would have not made so many hymns/prayers of Shiva, Shakti and Bhaj Govindam. He wrote lot of summaries on Upanishads and Bhagwat Geeta and Upanishads are part of Veda, that are way way older than Buddhists

Comment: Many of Buddha's followers were Vedic Brahmins prior to Buddha's time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Sankaracharya accused as Pracchana Bauddha (crypto-buddhist) by many Vedantins?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17249/why-is-sankaracharya-accused-as-pracchana-bauddha-crypto-buddhist-by-many-veda)

Answer (score 6):

Shankaracharya says in his work *Upadesa Sahasri* (*A Thousand Teachings*, Swami Jagadananda translator) verse 6:

> ...He [the teacher, the guru] should first of all teach the *Sruti* texts [vedic] establishing the oneness of the Self with *Brahman* such as "My child, in the beginning it (the universe) was Existence only, one alone without a second" (Chhandogya Upanishad 6.2.1), Where one sees nothing else (Chh. U. 7.24.1), "All this is bu the Self" (Chh. U. 7.25.2), "In the beginning all this was but the one Self" (Aitareya Upanishad 1.1.1), and "All this is verily *Brahman*." (Chh. U. 3.14.1)

and further in verses 7 and 8:

> After teaching these he should teach the definition of *Brahman* through such *Sruti* texts as "The Self devoid of sins" (Chh U. 8.7.1), "The *Brahman* that is immediate and direct" (Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 3.4.1), "That which is beyond hunger and thirst" (Br. U. 3.5.1), "Not-this, not-this" (Br. U. 2.3.6), "Neither gross nor subtle" (Br. U. 3.8.8), "This Self is not-this" (Br. U. 3.9.26), ""It is the Seer Itself unseen" (Br. U. 3.8.11), "Knowledge-Bliss" (Br. U. sloka 7, under 3.9.27), "Existence-Knowledge-Infinite" (Taittareya Upanishad 2.1), "Imperceptible bodiless" (Tai. U. 2.7), "That great unborn Self" (Br. U. 4.4.22), "Without the vital forces and the mind" (Mundaka Upanishad 2.1.2), "Unborn, comprising the interior and exterior" (Mu. U. 2.1.2), "Consisting of Knowledge only" (Br. U. 2.4.12), "Without interior or exterior" (Br. U. 2.5.19), "It is verily beyond what is known as also what is unknown" (Kena Upansihad 1.3) and "Called *Akasha* (the self-effulgent One)" (Chh. U. 8.14.1), and also through such *Smriti* texts as the following: "It is neither born nor dies" (Bh. Gita 2.20), "It is not affected by anybody's sins" (Bh. Gita 5.15), "Just as air is always in the ether" (Bh. Gita 9.6), "The individual Self should be regarded as the universal one" (Bh. Gita 13.2), "It is called neither existent nor non-existent" (Bh. Gita 13.12), "As the Self is beginningless and devoid of all qualities" (Bh. Gita 13.31), "The same in all beings" (Bh. Gita 13.27), and "The Supreme Being is different" (Bh. Gita 15.17); --all these support the definition given by the *Srutis* and prove the innermost Self is beyond transmigratory existence and that it is not different from *Brahman*, the all-comprehensive principle.

Chandradhar Sharma gives some other examples of references in the Rig Veda is his section on the vedas in his book here - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey. He also goes into the development/evolution of the concept of maya. You might also like reading the first 2 chapters of the Brahma Sutras (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras). It deals with the definition of Brahman. Vireswarananda goes inot the various definitions in his Introduction and the second section - Adhyasa - deals with Shankara's concept of Maya.